# How to get total number of tweets for a particular keyword search through twitter api?

Tags: twitter, tweets

I am building a simple application where I am searching for tweets related to keywords through twitter apis. Now the API restricts the result to default 15 and maximum 100. I want to know atleast how many total tweets are there for that keyword. I dont want to continue fetching till the results end to get the total count. Is there a simple way without going through the above exercise ?

Thanks in advance.